# Should my metronome be stored wound or unwound?

Tags: metronomes, storage

I have a mechanical metronome, I was wondering if at night I should let it run until it stops. How about if I go on vacation?

What makes me ask this is when I got my metronome it was wound up and I was freaked out that it wouldn't work because it might have been stored that way for a long time.

Comment: This sounds like a wind-up... You're more likely to wear out its click leaving it running overtime.

Comment: If the manufacturer is ok leaving it wound for long period of time it's probably ok.

Comment: @b3ko yeah I wasn't sure if it was the manufacturer or maybe somebody had it before me, returned it to the store, etc.

Comment: Do you feel you might be getting a bit desperate for attention, @foreyez?   :-)

Comment: @LaurencePayne I just bought an expensive metronome (after I bought a cheap one). I just didn't want it to get messed up. https://www.amazon.com/Wittner-903030-Super-Mini-Mahogany-Metronome/dp/B00380O9V0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole thing about spring steel is... it's springy.

There are working clocks that have been running for a hundred years without needing a new spring. They might need winding fractionally more than when they were new, but they'll keep going another hundred before they'll need a new spring.